# Console.ReadKey is processing the last item before quitting

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a tiny command line utility which reads user input and adds all input to a list. When the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed, the program is quit. However, upon pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, even the Escape key is being added to list and then the program quits.

How can I prevent the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key from being added to the list?

Code:

```
    ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
    List<string> stuffs = new List<string>();

    Console.WriteLine("Press Escape (Esc) to quit the program.");

    do {
        cki = Console.ReadKey();
        stuffs.Add(cki.Key.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
    } while(cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

    Console.WriteLine("You have entered the following data:");

    foreach(string stuff in stuffs)
        Console.WriteLine(stuff);
```

Comment: Deleting my answer - looks like I was a little too slow and also came up with exactly the same code as my illustrious co-answerers, no point in leaving duplicate answers around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the loop so that you check the value prior to adding it to your list.  For example, this loops the same, but breaks when Escape is pressed:

```
while(true)
{
    cki = Console.ReadKey();
    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
       break;

    stuffs.Add(cki.Key.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: or if you're extra daring: `while((cki = Console.ReadKey()) != ConsoleKey.Escape)`

Comment: @Reed: Your solution is working. The Esc key is not added to the list,  but I still see an arrow `←` when Esc key is pressed.

Comment: @Kishor Nanda - try `cki = Console.ReadKey(true)` and then a `Console.Write(cki.KeyChar);` after the `if` block.

Answer (score 3):

Check for the escape key inside the loop, but before processing:

```
do {
    cki = Console.ReadKey();
    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;
    stuffs.Add(cki.Key.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
} while(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn your do while loop on its head so it doesn't do the processing before checking the condition:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press Escape (Esc) to quit the program.");

cki = Console.ReadKey();
while(cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape) {
    stuffs.Add(cki.Key.ToString());
    cki = Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just simplify the while like so...

```
while ((cki = Console.ReadKey()).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    stuffs.Add(cki.Key.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is quite compact. Thanks for the tip.